# Unable to hide custom subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I've created a subview (which looks a lot like an alertview with spinner) for iOS 7, and leveraged the iOS 7 custom alertview from wimagguc (ios-custom-alertview on git).  Using ARC.  The issue I have is I show the view while processing, then call to close when processing is complete, but is still showing on screen.

Connection.m (EDIT)

```
 UIActivityIndicatorView *aSpinnerCustom;
 CustomIOS7AlertView *alertViewCustom;

 - (void)showWaittingAlert:(BOOL)isShow {

NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
float ver_float = [ver floatValue];

// custom alert view for iOS 7 from AlertViewCustom folder
alertViewCustom = [[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] init];

//spinner to be added to iOS 7 AlertView
aSpinnerCustom = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]  initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

//label to be used as subview to help text and spinner
alertTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 75)];

//label of app name
UILabel *subTitleApp;
subTitleApp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 40)];
subTitleApp.text = APP_NAME;
subTitleApp.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];
subTitleApp.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
subTitleApp.numberOfLines = 0;

//label of processing
UILabel *subTitle;
subTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 25, 250, 25)];
subTitle.text = @"processing...";
subTitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
subTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

//set height of spinner in custom alertview
aSpinnerCustom.frame = CGRectMake(round((alertTitle.frame.size.width - 25) / 2), round(alertTitle.frame.size.height - 30), 25, 25);
aSpinnerCustom.tag  = 1;

// adding text and spinner to alertview
[alertTitle addSubview:aSpinnerCustom];
[alertTitle addSubview:subTitleApp];
[alertTitle addSubview:subTitle];

//adding label to custom alertview
[alertViewCustom setContainerView:alertTitle];

[alertViewCustom setButtonTitles:NULL];

    if (isShow) {
        [alertViewCustom show];
        [aSpinnerCustom startAnimating];
        NSLog(@"%@",@"showWaitingAlert Show iOS 7");

    }else {
        [alertViewCustom close];
        [aSpinnerCustom stopAnimating];

        NSLog(@"%@",@"showWaitingAlert Stop iOS 7");

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, my subview was created each time the method was called.  I included an if alertview == nil so it wasn't created twice.  Thanks @trojanfoe for your help as well.

```
 if (alertViewCustom == nil){
 setup view code here..
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using the wrong combination of instance variable and property names.  I personally never use auto-generated `@synthesize` methods and would recode your class like this:

.h file:

```
@interface ConnectionManager : NSObject {
    UIActivityIndicatorView   *_aSpinnerCustom;
    CustomIOS7AlertView *_alertViewCustom;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *aSpinnerCustom;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomIOS7AlertView *alertViewCustom;
```

.m file:

```
// Be explicit
@synthesize aSpinnerCustom = _aSpinnerCustom;
@synthesize alertViewCustom = _alertViewCustom;
```

and then change every reference to `aSpinnerCustom` and `alertViewCustom` to `self.aSpinnerCustom` and `self.alertViewCustom`.  Never reference the instance variables directly in a non-ARC environment.

What's happening with your code is the auto-generated `@synthesize` methods have created backing variables starting with `_`, alongside the ones you created and as you use `alertViewCustom` sometimes and `self.alertViewCustom` at other times the wrong object references are being used.

And don't forget your `dealloc` method should use `self.whatever = nil;` in order to release the objects.

Comment: @Jonah.at.GoDaddy I assume he wasn't using ARC based on his `@property` attributes and I don't think your suggestion is better as I believe this is confusing the OP.

Comment: Using ARC.  I edited the code, removed the property in .h and synthesize in .m.  The solution above did not work.  Thoughts on new code?